# How can I extract uniqued caterogies from JSON in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter

I have a JSON

[{"id":495, "title":"BSB", "category":null},{"id":495, "title":"BCB", "category":"temp"},{"id":495, "title":"BSB", "category":"temp"},{"id":495, "title":"BSB", "category":"cat12"},...]

I want to extract uniqued categories in a list without contain null value in Flutter. Example: List ["temp","cat12"...]

How to use model to fetch the categories from JSON?

Thanks in advance.

My current model.dart:

```
List<Product> productFromJson(String str) => List<Product>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Product.fromJson(x)));

String productToJson(List<Product> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Product {
    Product({
        this.id,
        this.title,
        this.category,
    });

    int id;
    String title;
    String category;

    factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        category: json["category"] == null ? null : json["category"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "category": category == null ? null : category,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// @dart=2.12
void doSomething() {
  var list = [{"id":495, "title":"BSB", "category":null},{"id":495, "title":"BCB", "category":"temp"},{"id":495, "title":"BSB", "category":"temp"},{"id":495, "title":"BSB", "category":"cat12"}];
  var myList = list.map((m) => m['category']).toSet().where((e) => e != null);
  print(myList);
}

void main() {
  doSomething();
}
```

Result:

```
(temp, cat12)
```

Comment: How can I fetch it from JSON?

Comment: How to use model to fetch the categories?